# I have a problem with the strpos & substr function on PHP

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I have a problem with the strpos & substr function, thank you for your help:

```
$temp = "U:hhp|E:123@gmail.com,P:h123";

$find_or = strpos($temp,"|");
$find_and = strpos($temp,",");

$find_user = substr($temp,2,$find_or-2);
$find_email = substr($temp,$find_or+3,$find_and);
$find_passeord = substr($temp,$find_and+3,strlen($temp));

echo("$find_user+$find_email+$find_passeord<br/>");
```

/************************************/

Why is the output like this ??

```
hhp+123@gmail.com,P:h123 +h123
```

but i want this:

```
hhp+123@gmail.com,h123
```

Comment: The problem is that `substr()`'s third parameter is the length and not the end position.

Comment: What output are you looking for would help?  It like this cause that is what your code does

Comment: A regular expression would be a better way to do this.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, that was not there when I added my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$find_and` is the index of `,`, but the third argument to `substr()` needs to be the length of the substring, not the ending index. So

```
$find_email = substr($temp,$find_or+3,$find_and);
```

should be

```
$find_email = substr($temp,$find_or+3,$find_and-$find_or-3);
```

For `$find_passeord` you can omit the 3rd argument, since the default is the end of the string.

However, this would be simpler with a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^U:(.*?)\|E:(.*?),P:(.*)/', $temp, $match)) {
    list($whole, $user, $email, $password) = $match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over the input I would suggest

```php
$temp = "U:hhp|E:123@gmail.com|P:h123";
list($user, $email, $password) = explode("|",$temp);
$user = explode(":",$user)[1];
$email = explode(":",$email)[1];
$password = explode(":",$password)[1];
```

if not then I still recommend exploding the string into parts and work your way down to what you need .  https://3v4l.org/ is a great site for testing php code ... here is an example of this working https://3v4l.org/upEGG

Answer (score 0):

Echoing what Barmar just said in a comment, **regular expressions** are definitely the best way to "break up a string."  (It is quite-literally much of what they are *for.)*  This is the **preg_** family of PHP functions. *(e.g.* `preg_match`, `preg_match_all`, `preg_replace`.)

The million-dollar idea behind a "regular expression" is that it is a string-matching *pattern.*  If the string "matches" that pattern, you can easily extract the exact substrings which matched *portions* of it.

In short, **all** of the `strpos/substr` logic that you are right now wrestling with ... *"goes away!"*  **Poof.**

For example, this pattern:  `^(.*)|(.*),(.*)$` ...

It says:  "Anchored at the beginning of the string `^`, capture `()` a pattern consisting of "zero or more occurrences of any character `(.*)`, until you encounter a literal `|`.  Now, for the second group, proceed until you find a `,`.  Then, for the third group, proceed to take any character until the end of the string `$`."

You can "match" that regular expression and simply *be handed* all three of these groups!  (As well as "the total string that matched.")  And you didn't have to "write" a thing!

There are *thousands* of web pages by now which discuss this "remarkable 'programming language' within a single cryptic string."  But it just might be **the** most pragmatically-useful technology for any practitioner to know, and *every* programming language somehow implements it, more-or-less following the precedent first set by the (still active) programming language, `Perl`.

Comment: Great selling pitch for regular expressions, but it doesn't actually address the OP's problem. Have you considered a career in used car sales?